# Regex how to match an optional character in front of a greedy capture?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python re. I have a string in the following format:

```
<root>.<entry_2>.<entry_3>.<entry_4>.<entry_5>...<entry_n>-<op_1>:<op_2>=<value>`
```

I would like to capture four groups: `.<entry_2>.<entry_3>...<entry_n>` in one group, `<op_1>` in a second group, `<op_2>` in a third group, and `<value>` in the fourth group. However, I would also like `-<op_1>` to be optional. So, if `-` doesn't exist, then the second group returns empty. My current matching expression is `^.+?(\..+)[-](.*):(.*)=(.*)`. But `[-]` and `[:]` require those characters in order to match. And making them optional forces the first capture to overrun the `-` and `:` characters if they do exist. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Please Format Your Code More Properly, It Is Not Easily Readable

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Alot Better @Espresso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> s = '<root>.<entry_2>.<entry_3>.<entry_4>.<entry_5>...<entry_10>-<op_1>:<op_2>=<value>'
>>> re.findall(r'(\.<entry_.*entry_\d+>)(?:-(<op_\d+>))?:(<op_\d+>)=(<[^>]+>)', s)
[('.<entry_2>.<entry_3>.<entry_4>.<entry_5>...<entry_10>', '<op_1>', '<op_2>', '<value>')]

>>> s = '<root>.<entry_2>.<entry_3>.<entry_4>.<entry_5>...<entry_10>:<op_2>=<value>'
>>> re.findall(r'(\.<entry_.*entry_\d+>)(?:-(<op_\d+>))?:(<op_\d+>)=(<[^>]+>)', s)
[('.<entry_2>.<entry_3>.<entry_4>.<entry_5>...<entry_10>', '', '<op_2>', '<value>')]
```

I have changed `entry_n` to `entry_10` so that it has digits instead of `n` for the code snippet to work.

`^\+spm_.+?` isn't present in input sample, so I didn't include it, but you can add it if you need it

The four groups are:

- `(\.<entry_.*entry_\d+>)`
- `(?:-(<op_\d+>))?` --> optional group
- `:(<op_\d+>)`
- `=(<[^>]+>)`

You can also use `re.search(r'pat', s).groups()` but you will get `None` instead of empty string for the optional group. Forgot that you could change it, use `.groups(default='')` to get empty string instead of `None`